# Is there a way to find out what function was called within a list comprehension in another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bytecode, analysis

Lets say I'm given a file `test.py` with the following contents:

```
def helper():
    pass


def test():
    foo = [helper() for _ in range(5)]
    return foo
```

Now in another file I want to `import test`. And then I want to find out what functions were called in `test.test`. Specifically, I want to be able to know that the function `helper` was called (just the function name as a string is sufficient).

Is there any way to go about doing that? (no string parsing please, as you can get around it by having a comment for example)

Answer (score 0):

so basically when helper() is executed it returns a string in this case 'helper', so now when you execute the function in the list comprehension it returns that string (in this case 5 times) so if u printed test() and it returned foo u would get a list of 'helper' however if u just returned first item in foo like this foo[0] it would return 'helper'

```
def helper():
    return 'helper'


def test():
    foo = [helper() for _ in range(5)]
    return foo[0]


print(test())
```

Comment: I cannot edit the helper function, so this won't work

Comment: @HHC ok so you have completely no access to the function helper? are you importing it?

Comment: because you do not have to edit the function directly to add functionality. they are called decorators and I do not really know about them much but here is a video that may be helpful [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FsAPt_9Bf3U) However it will still require you to do some changes to test.py